# LineageOS encryption not working dispite being told it is

Tags: nexus-5, encryption, lineageos, disk-encryption

I used to use cyanogenmod 13 on my nexus 5, i had the encryption enabled and it would ask me for my passcode at boot and i could not access any data from anything until i did this.

I've now updated to latest version of liniageOS and  recently noticed i am not having to enter this passcode at all, and that while the UI in the setting says i am encrypted, this is false information as i can access any data on my device either from recovery or from adb via usb.
I try to tap on the area where it says encrypted so i can re-encrypt it and it just does nothing.

I have herd about the massive bug/back door google have caused relating to accessibility features, however under accessibility i have the accessibility services for lastpass and comodo etc turned OFF, the only option on this page enabled is screen auto-rotate.

How can i encrypt my phone with this ROM, or can i not and i should ditch it ASAP and get a more security centric one? If so what would be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you have default encryption where the password is `default_password`. You need root privilege for ADB.

Issue command in shell:

```
adb root
adb shell vdc cryptfs verifypw default
```

to check that.

You can always change the encryption password from UI and require that password at boot (preboot authentication) or much secure, [define different lock screen && encryption passwords](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187023/245102)