# Is my phone encrypted with my password?

Tags: encryption, password, lineageos

I have a Galaxy S5 running LineageOS 14.1.

The device settings state that the device is encrypted.

I set up a password, and select to require password at boot.

I then set up a PIN for unlocking the screen, but did not select to require PIN at boot.

When I boot the phone, it does not ask for the password to boot and only the PIN is required for unlocking the screen.

Is my phone encrypted with my password?

Comment: Have you taken look at the Logcat? It sounds like encryption is not working.. However, if the pin is asked for before even the lock screen appears then yes it is encrypted.

Comment: How do I use logcat to determine that encryption is working?

Comment: Is your recovery TWRP? If it is, you could boot into it and see whether it asks for any kind of password in order to mount `/data`. If it does ask, or if it has problems while trying to mount `/data`, then encryption is working just fine.

Comment: @Paul, did you try to follow Ka1S3 answer?

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes, although I don't recall all of details, but the answer is no longer applicable due to a change in AOSP. However, what I described in my question is a condition where there is some sort of default password for unlocking encrypted AOSP. This default password is actually known by the TWRP project, because TWRP will automatically attempt to use the default password to unlock. However, if I select to encrypt with the PIN, theoretically the PIN is uniquely useful to decrypt on each phone. Thus, the PIN is very secure, with the exception of an over-the-shoulder attack.

Answer (score 2):

You device is encrypted, but PIN is used for unlocking master key.

From

*I set up a password, and select to require password at boot. I then set up a PIN for unlocking the screen, but did not select to require PIN at boot.*

we can assume that you wanted different lock screen && encryption passwords.

Because you are using LineageOS, acquiring root for ADB is not issue.

For achieving what you presumably intended 1st define lock screen password or PIN - select *Require password/PIN to start device*. Lock device && do a power cycle - not every1 will agree with this procedure, but I tend to verify.

After successful bootstrap, for different encryption password you should either change password via ADB or terminal or purpose built application - 
[SnooperStopper](https://f-droid.org/packages/cz.eutopia.snooperstopper/) or [Cryptfs password manager](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.nick.cryptfs.passwdmanager/)

If you preffer ADB or terminal, while in shell, issue

```
adb root && sleep 2 && adb shell "vdc cryptfs changepw password [curent PIN/password] [new password]"
```

and hit return; if terminal is only option for you, issue only

```
vdc cryptfs changepw password [curent PIN/password] [new password]
```

You should always verify PW with

```
vdc cryptfs verifypw [PIN/password]
```